# JavaScript unescape equivalent in Java

Tags: java

I want to find a substitute for javascript unescape in java

I have tried this and it has not worked for me

```
String cadena = "%u0032%u0038";
System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(cadena, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: There’s probably no direct equivalent since `unescape` is very JavaScript specific and not generally useful, and [its use is discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape). If you try using `decodeURI` on your input, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `unescape()` method yourself.

In Java 11+, you can do it like this:

```java
public static String unescape(String s) {
    return Pattern.compile("%u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})").matcher(s).replaceAll(m ->
            Character.toString(Integer.parseInt(m.group(m.start(1) != -1 ? 1 : 2), 16)));
}
```

In earlier Java versions, use:

```java
public static String unescape(String s) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})").matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        m.appendReplacement(buf, new String(new int[] { Integer.parseInt(m.group(m.start(1) != -1 ? 1 : 2), 16) }, 0, 1));
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
String cadena = "%u0032%u0038";
System.out.println(unescape(cadena));
```

*Output*

```
28
```